# Facebook Audience Network Ads not showing but test Ads are showing

Tags: java, android-studio, facebook-ads

I'm using Facebook Audience Network Ads in my Android app. The problem is test ads are showing perfectly but when I replace the ad ID with real Banner Ad ID and build the release-apk, the ads are not showing.
The older version of the app on the play store perfectly showing the ads with the same Banner-Ad ID.
Can anybody help me what could be the problem.

```
    AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);

    final AdView adView;
    // AdSettings.addTestDevice("f170c092-ed4f-4274-973a-c036f00b9fb0");
    adView = new AdView(this, "692851284711992_693363344660786", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

    // Find the Ad Container
    final LinearLayout adContainer = findViewById(R.id.BannerAdViewPager);


    // Add the ad view to your activity layout
    adContainer.addView(adView);

    // Request an ad
    adView.loadAd();
```

'''

Comment: Did you find solution for this ? I've the same problem now

Comment: The real ads only show if the app is published on play store.

Comment: App is published on play store but devices test ads only is shown. Devices not listed on devices tests doesn't shown ads

Comment: App is published on play store but devices test ads only is shown. Devices not listed on devices tests doesn't shown ads. Also facing the problem. Any solution? @Goms

Comment: Now we have to switch to the auction system. The cascade system is no longer relevant.

I have used Tapdaq and it works pretty well with FAN

Comment: Any solution... ? Please help